# OpenGL Enable Clip Distance

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, clip

I'm trying to render a proper refraction/reflection in my OpenGL project and I need to use clip distance. I'm following the tutorial by [Thin Matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NH9k4zTAqk&).

I enable the clip distance with

```
glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
```

in my game loop and then I try to use it in the vertex shader like this

```
gl_ClipDistance[0] = -1;
```

I've tried to change around the -1 value but nothing happens no matter what I do. Is there something more I need to do to enable it properly?

Answer (score 6):

The `gl_ClipDistance` array contains a series of floating-point values that represent, for each vertex, which side of a conceptual "plane" it is on. Each array index is a conceptual "plane". The vertex can be either on the negative side, or the non-negative side.

If two vertices of the same line/triangle are on two difference sides of the plane (that is, one vertex has a negative value and the other a non-negative one), then the primitive will be clipped at the location where that distance is 0. The part of the primitive on the non-negative side will be visible.

Given that, what you need to do is set up a clip distance value that represents the distance between the vertex position and the plane you want to clip against. The standard plane equation (Ax + By + Cz + D = 0) gives us a way to handle this. The distance of a point from the plane A, B, C, D, assuming the vector (A, B, C) is a unit vector, is simply:

```
dot(point, vec3(A, B, C)) + D
```

This also assumes that `point` is in the same space as A, B, C and D.

Of course, if `point` is a `vec4`, with the last component as 1.0, then you can just do this:

```
dot(point, plane);
```

Where `plane` is a `vec4` that contains A, B, C, and D. And that's your clip distance.

You also need to redeclare `gl_ClipDistance` with an explicit size in the shader stage that uses it. In GLSL 3.20+, `gl_ClipDistance` lives inside an interface block, so you have to redeclare that:

```
out gl_PerVertex
{
  vec4 gl_Position;
  float gl_ClipDistance[1];
};
```

Comment: Note that the specs do not allow you to redeclare interface blocks in #version 330 core. The correct way for OpenGL <= 4.1 should thus be: "out float gl_ClipDistance[1];" I found this out through the [glslangValidator tool](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/issues/1441)