# How to draw part of mesh correctly in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have two planes(draw them with VAO and EBO), all planes i generate(It looks like a grid). Firstly i draw only boarders of these planes.

[image]

Colors for each plane predefined.

I wan't to move one plane(red plane) and fill with colors part of black plane(Only that cells, that behind red plane). So, i want to know, how to do it correctly in openGL.

All planes looks like a grid
[image]

My planes

[image]

Start to move one of the plane
[image]

[image]

I want to fill colors this part of plane in yellow circle.

[image]

Yellow arrow shows the plain which we moved. Pink arrow shows the boarder of this plane
White circle shows part of mesh, which i want to visualize while moving a plane in image above

[image]

White arrow shows where plane that we moved is located

Comment: What do you mean by "fill with colors part of black plane" and "only that cells that **behind** red plane"? Do you mean that the pixels where both planes overlap on screen should be using the color of the black plane instead of the red plane?

Comment: Hi, what you want to achieve is unclear. Would you rephrase or maybe draw an explicit figure ?

Comment: @limserhane
I edited my question, maybe became more clearly

Comment: @Botje I edited my question, maybe became more clearly

Comment: I've never used Qt3D

Comment: @Rabbid76 QVector3D is a part of QT3D? I just get a pointer to pure openGL functions and use them

Comment: @Rabbid76 I created a image for you. No, i haven't problems with math

Comment: You can see that i want to draw only part of plane, that behind plane that we moved

Comment: So this is a question about clipping? You want to cut off the plane?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, i want to cut off the plane

Comment: @АндрейПетров see [Vertex Post-Processing - User-defined clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#User-defined_clipping) and [OpenGL Enable Clip Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650325/opengl-enable-clip-distance)

Comment: You want to change the coordinates of the sides of the cube, so they don't touch the blue/green lines. It's a rectangular cuboid.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-calculate the coordinates for all 6 sides of the cube (or at least 5 sides, since the side opposite the moving side doesn't move).

Consider the side that touches the red and blue arrows in your picture - the one closest to the camera. I guess that the moving side moved to about X=0.25. So work out the coordinates for a cube that stops at 0.25 instead of 0. Draw it on graph paper if you want. This is quite simple and I don't want to simply give you the answer, because you will probably learn more by doing it yourself.

Then render those coordinates.